# a Simple "Hello World" Inline Assembly language Program in C/C++

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

i use devcpp and borland c compiler....

```
asm {
    mov ax,4       // (I/O Func.)
    mov bx,1       // (Output func)  
    mov cx,&name   // (address of the string)
    mov dx,6       // (length of the string)
    int 0x21       // system call
}
```

in the above code snippets i want to print a string with the help of assembly language...
but how can i put the address of the string in register cx....

is there something wrong in code???

Comment: 0x21 - wow kudos for getting to basics :-)

Comment: How is the string being stored? i.e: What's the declaration of `name`?

Comment: I suggest to ignore the 16 bit real-mode assembler and directly start with 32 bit assembler. It's much easier and much more practical these days.

Comment: well thanx....
but is there any way to get the address of string and put back in the cx register...
or have u ever tried inline assembly...
i need just a little help...so i can start with asm...
any example???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the Borland compiler on hand, so I might be misremembering its syntax, but have you tried this:

```
asm {
    mov ax,4       // (I/O Func.)
    mov bx,1       // (Output func)  
    lds cx,"Hello, world" // (address of the string)
    mov dx,6       //  (length of the string)
    int 0x21       // system call
}
```

or this:

```
char msg[] = "Hello, world";

asm {
    mov ax,4       // (I/O Func.)
    mov bx,1       // (Output func)  
    lds cx, msg   // (address of the string)
    mov dx,6       //  (length of the string)
    int 0x21       // system call
}
```

**edit:** although this will compile (now that I've changed MOV to LDS), it will still throw an error at runtime. I'll try again...

Comment: no it doesnt work...
it gives error........
is there any other way by which i can get the address of string..and put then back to the cx register....

Comment: As far I know, `mov cx,msg` put `msg`'s address into `cx` register. What are you getting?

Comment: @vs4vijay You shouldn't accept not working solution as an answer because it is missleading.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the variable name in there:

```
mov ax,4       // (I/O Func.)
mov bx,1       // (Output func)  
mov cx,name   // (address of the string)
mov dx,6       //  (lenght of the string)
int 0x21       // system call
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not too good at assembly.</sub>