# Simple x86-64 C++ Inline assembly "Hello World" example

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am trying to find a very basic C++ inline x86-64 assembly example, similar to this:

[a Simple "Hello World" Inline Assembly language Program in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179183/a-simple-hello-world-inline-assembly-language-program-in-c-c)

```
char msg[] = "Hello, world";

asm {
    mov ax,4       // (I/O Func.)
    mov bx,1       // (Output func)  
    lds cx, msg   // (address of the string)
    mov dx,6       //  (lenght of the string)
    int 0x21       // system call
}
```

which would work with the Intel Compiler. Could someone please help with this?

EDIT Regarding OS I have the ICC on Windows and Linux- lets say Linux!

Comment: What OS? Normally you don't use `int 0x21` (DOS interrupt) in x86-64 code.

Comment: Google `intel compiler inline assembly`

Comment: If you are on Windows, Try [DosBox(x86 emulator)](http://www.dosbox.com/) to use `0x21` interrupt.

Comment: @Alex It's true that the question isn't great - it doesn't show any attempts or research - but still I find your suggestion puzzling. Inline asm syntax for this is probably way easier to find than finding the right interrupt for your OS/the calling conventions for the library function you want to use/etc ...

Comment: @us2012 I see what you mean; I read it as "How do I embed assembly using the Intel Compiler?"

Comment: For hello world in Linux x86-64 assembly, see [“Hello World” in 64-bit Linux Assembly](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/05/64-bit-hello-world-in-linux-assembly-nasm/) (code in NASM syntax, converting to Intel C++ Compiler inline assembly shouldn't be too difficult).

Comment: @us2012 except for the similar question I found and posted....

Answer (score 5):

The code you have posted is 16-bit code. 64-bit Windows (or any version of Linux) doesn't support 16-bit code. [And it's a bit buggy, since it sets the length to 6, when the actual length of the string is 12...]

You could possibly figure out how to do the same thing in Windows code, but I fail to see the point of learning how to make system calls in Windows from assembler. Write some code that does something that you can actually apply in real life, such as counting the number of characters in a string.

Of course, you will need to use either Intel or GCC compilers, since the Microsoft compiler doesn't allow inline assembler in 64-bit mode.

Here's a little sample of inline assembler using the "read timestamp counter" instruction, which will work with the gcc compiler (and by compatibility should work with the Intel compiler too).

```
static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}
```

Comment: I just wanted an example- a small example, of some x86-64 assembly which is inlined within a normal C++ main function

Comment: Regarding assembly, there is Intel syntax and the AT&T syntax.  The answer provided by Mats is AT&T syntax, like this: __asm__ __volatile__("mov %0, %0" : "+r" (dummy));  That whole statement can be placed inline.

Comment: @PeterL. what is the difference between syntaxes? I use/will use Intel C++ compiler in VS2010 and Eclipse on Windows/Linux

Comment: @mezamorphic  Added my comment as an answer below because I can't figure out how to format code in a comment. :/

Answer (score 1):

AT&T vs. Intel assembly format.

```
at&t noprefix                   intel
mov eax, -4(ebp,edx,4)          mov DWORD PTR[-4 +ebp +edx *4], eax
mov eax, -4(ebp)                mov DWORD PTR[-4 +ebp], eax
mov edx, (ecx)                  mov DWORD PTR[ecx], edx
lea (   ,eax,4), eax            lea eax, DWORD PTR[8 + eax*4]
lea (eax,eax,2), eax            lea eax, DWORD PTR[eax*2+eax]
```

Or this.

```
asm(".intel_syntax noprefix");
asm("mov eax, ebx");

asm(".att_syntax prefix");
asm("mov %ebx, %eax");
```

AT&T syntax.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int x=1, f=2, fa=3;
asm("int $0x3");
asm("mov 4%0,%%eax"::"m"(x));
asm("movss 4%0,%%xmm1"::"m"(f));
asm("fld 4%0"::"m"(fa));
return 0;
}
```

Note that one difference is the use of '%' and the direction of assignment to a register.

Some more discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972602/att-vs-intel-syntax-and-limitations) and [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly).  Much of that has to do with debugging.